# How to reformat a time machine drive to use on a PC

Tags: mac, hard-drive, time-machine, backup, pc

My sister used to be a mac user and recently switched to a PC. She has her mac stuff backed up on  two hard drives, one is formatted as a time machine. We've transferred all her important files to the other one that is not a time machine, so the time machine one is empty. She wants to use the time machine one as a backup drive for her PC but I"m not sure how to get it to reformat... help?

Answer (score 2):

Ages ago it was just 'fdisk', but now Microsoft suggests this: Start/Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Computer Mangement/Storage/Disk Management/Format

Ref: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-format-hard-disk-partition#create-format-hard-disk-partition=windows-7